# Finding $\int^{\infty}_{0}{\frac{1}{(x+b)^{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\exp\left\{-\frac{a^2}{2x}\right\}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I got the following integration and I could not figure it out, when I used WolframAlpha it gives something with $\rm erfc$ function. I wonder if it has other solution or not.

$$\int\limits^{\infty}_{0}{\frac{1}{(x+b)^{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\exp\left\{-\frac{a^2}{2x}\right\}}\,dx$$

where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: According to Mathematica, this is $$\frac{\pi(a^2+b)\text{erfc}(a/\sqrt{2b})e^{a^2/(2b)}-a\sqrt{2\pi b}}{2b^{5/2}}.$$ I don't see how to get there at the moment, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give you a way that will lead to a solution as in the comment I gave you. Let $1/x=u^2$, and you will get the integral
$$
2\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-(au)^2/2}\frac{u^2}{(1+bu^2)^2}\,du
$$
After a partial fraction decomposition of the rational part, we get
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-(au)^2/2}\biggl(\frac{2}{b(1+bu^2)}-\frac{2}{b(1+bu^2)^2}\biggr)\,du
$$
Then you can extend your function to the whole real line and proceed with the [Plancherel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem) together with the well-known Fourier transforms
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal F e^{-(au)^2/2}&=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{a}e^{-\xi^2/(2a)},\\
\mathcal F \frac{1}{1+bu^2}&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{b}}e^{-|\xi|/\sqrt{b}},\\
\mathcal F \frac{1}{(1+bu^2)^2}&=\frac{\pi}{2b}(\sqrt{b}+|\xi|)e^{-|\xi|/\sqrt{b}}.
\end{aligned}
$$
The complementary error function, erfc, will appear. It is defined by
$$
\text{erfc}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt.
$$
I leave you here, and hope that you will be able to complete...

Comment: nice @mickep (+1)

Comment: @mickep thanks for the solution, I think we cant get an answer without erfc function.